# About MS Excel, how to get a digit will be bold automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I need a formula in excel that if the digit exists in the row, it should get bold or change color automatically.

For example, I have this:

```
 A   B   C   D   E
 1   3   8   9   15
```

If I type `9`, the digit `9` in **D4** should get bold or change color to indicate that the number exist.

Is it possible?

Comment: "the digit 9 in D4" - your question is difficult to understand, please attach some sample data to help us understanding it.

Comment: ok 
if I type 9 in F1, I want the 9 in D4 get bold. 
of if I type 3 in F1, I want the 3 in B1 get bold.
Is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Conditional Formatting:

[image]

- Select the first cell of the row of numbers. I guess is `A1`.
- Open *Conditional Fomatting* and then *New Rule*.
- On type of rule, select *"Use a formula"*

[image]

- In the box put `=A1=$F$1`
- On the button *Format* select the format that you want, **Bold** for example.
- With the cell still selected use the **Format Painter** to copy this format to the other cells in the row.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I cannot believe it works.
I thought I could not follow you coz I am not good at it. 
Anyway, It was a great help. 
Thank you a lot.